# ASP.NET MVC: How to properly reference custom object to ApplicationUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

currently I am trying to connect my custom object to Application User, which is auto-generated by Visual Studio.

`Employee.cs`

```
public class Employee
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal MonthlySalary { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Experience { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string PhotoURL { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Error is:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to
>   retrieve metadata for Models.Tables.Employee. One or more validation
>   errors were detected during model generation: 
>   Parent_ApplicationUser_Target_Parent_ApplicationUser_Source: : The
>   types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential
>   constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the
>   Principal Role. The type of property 'ApplicationUserlD' on entity
>   'Parent' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity
>   'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint
>   'Parent_ApplicationUser. Employee ApplicationUser Target Employee
>   ApplicationUser Source:: The types of all properties in the Dependent
>   Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding
>   property types in the Principal Role. The type of property
>   'ApplicationUserlD' on entity 'Employee does not match the type of
>   property 'Id' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential
>   constraint 'Employee_ApplicationUser.

`Parent` table contains same `ApplicationUser` reference as `Employee`.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help

Comment: *The type of property 'ApplicationUserlD' on entity 'Parent' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'ApplicationUser'*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default (generated by VS while creating new project with CodeFirst), `ApplicationUser` has Id of type `string`. Your foreign key in `Employee` to `ApplicationUser` is of type `int`, so there is type mismatch.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  //Id in IdentityUser is of type string
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, changing type of `ApplicationUserID` to `string` solved the problem